How to transfer all uncommitted changes verbatim from one git repo to another?
I have 2 nearly identical repositories. One repository has some changes, with some files renamed, added and removed.
'git status' shows that files were removed, added, etc.
Same happens after 'git stash push' and 'git stash pop'.
However, when I create a patch with 'git diff' and then apply it to the other repository with 'git apply' - renamed files aren't added to the repository with their new names, and original files are left empty.
How to transfer current work from one repo to another without committing them such that moved/added/deleted files would be appropriately also added/deleted in the repository?

So, the files in question are tracked in one repo but not the other?

Yes. I would like to copy that tracking state into another repository.

I don't believe there is such a thing as "tracking state". A file is tracked because you've put it into the index (either by adding it or by checking out a commit which includes it); that isn't something you can copy from from one repo and paste into another. Maybe you could write a script that uses git ls-files on the first repo to get a list of tracked files and calls git add for those same files on the second repo.

"How to transfer current work from one repo to another without committing them ..." You could use another tool like rsync to synchronize a directory. If you want to keep another copy of the repo up to date, you could use multiple origins, just give the other origin a different name. Needs some care when using, of course.

Git does not track file renames or moves.  Instead, git determines on the fly when certain commands are executed if a file has been renamed or moved.
For this situation, we need to add the new file name to the index so it is tracked and so git diff will include the renamed/moved file.
git add -N <renamed/moved files>  # add the new filename to the index. -N means add the file empty so diff will include all lines
git diff -C > patchfile   # -C detect copies/renames/moves

then on the other git repo:
git apply patchfile


Note that renamed files will not be added to the second repository.  They will only be in the working tree. If you need them added to the repo, you will need to git add them
